# SSRS Report - SharePoint 2013 -> insert multiple Items in Report

Tags: reporting-services

is it possible to insert many SharePoint List Items in a Report? 

For Example:
The User writes five InventoryNumber in a field and the Report shows the relevant data...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, we can only get values from one list in one query. If you want to have multiple list item. You need to create multiple dataset for different lists. To render these data from different lists into one data region, you should use subreport.